# Xcode crashes when capabilities are added to Watch Extension

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, watchos, code-signing-entitlements

I just added HealthKit to my project for which you need to add the entitlement in the Signing & Capabilities Section to the respective target.

However, whereas everything worked fine with my iOS App, Xcode crashed after adding the capability to the Watch App Extension. At first nothing happened, but when I clicked on the iOS target again, it crashed.

Did anyone experience something similar?

Comment: kindly mention the Xcode version.

Comment: It is Xcode 11.3.1. However, I sorted that problem out. Somehow the entitlements file was at the wrong place in the project folder. So I created a custom property list and transformed it to a entitlements file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entitlements file was missing. I created a property list and changed it to an entitlements file. The reference in the info.plist refered to a entitlements file short cut, which was leading nowhere.